# Можно ли как-то при удержании кнопки канваса обрабатывать функцию скрипта Unity

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

То есть, когда зажимаешь button, то его функция срабатывает пока пользователь не отжал кнопку, можно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у `EventSystem` (класс, который отвечает за отлов событий ввода и автоматически добавляющийся при добавлении первого Canvas) есть ряд интерфейсов, которые позволят вам отслеживать любые действия с ним, касающиеся ввода.

Например, в вашем случае нужно два интерфейса [IPointerDownHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) и [IPointerUpHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html). Унаследуйте от них класс, который висит на кнопке и реализуйте их методы.

`PointerDown` срабатывает, когда ЛКМ была нажата над объектом, на котором висит скрипт. `PointerUp` - когда кнопка была отпущена.

Так же, думаю, вам нужно реализовать интерфейс [IPointerExitHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html), его метод вызывается, когда курсор покидает объект. Это вам понадобится для, чтобы отключать "зажатие", если игрок выводит курсор за пределы кнопки, при этом не отпуская зажатую кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

В скрипте использовать функцию Update(){}, и повесить скрипт на кнопку.